# too few arguments to function ‘memcpy’

Tags: c++, c, memory

what I understand is that memcpy must have 3 arguments:

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

so I am trying this code:

```
//char *tmpPtr is a pointer that points to some data
char frameBuffer[921600]; //destination starting a given index
int bufferIndex;//the given index
memccpy(frameBuffer+bufferIndex,tmpPtr,Data.size()-1);
```

but I am getting this error:

> error: too few arguments to function `void * memccpy (void *, const
>   void *, int, size_t)

Comment: How on earth is this to localized!!! It is about functions from the standard libraries used by C programmers. It involves a real error message and can be accurately answered. It is very likely to help people in the future that have this type of error  (too few arguments can happen quite often misspelling is the major reason) this illustrates this perfectly.

Comment: @LokiAstari it is localized because It's my fault in typing the function's name, sorry for that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Typo:

```
memccpy
   ^^
```

You called the wrong function.

`memccpy` also takes a character (as an `int` argument) upon encountering which the copy shall be stopped.

Comment: my Bad !! Thank you i have been working for 18 hours on this project, do I have to delete the question??

Comment: You can't delete it anymore, it has an upvoted answer. I guess it could be closed as too localized and maybe deleted the normal way thereafter.

Comment: ok , I will accept your answer in 8 min

Comment: my 2c would be to actually leave it here - it has definitely helped me (and, at least other 20 people ;) because whoever wrote this methods' name ought to be kicked in the butt... I mean, come on...

Comment: Yeah this is a very useful question for beginners since I just rushed through with tab completion without realizing that there are two very similar functions